# React stackable snackbars/toasts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, snackbar

I'm creating my own simple snackbar/toast stacker. However, I'm having problems with queing them in an orderly manner. Removing a snackbar from the snackbar que causes re-render and odd behavior.

The basic flow:
Click a button which causes the addSnack function to fire which is provided by the withSnackbar HOC.

Take the parameters from the fired function, and create a snack accordingly and add it to the snackbar list.

At the end, we render the snackbar list.

Each snackbar controls it's own appearance and disappearance, and is controlled by a time out. After the timeout is fired, it calls removeSnack function which is suppose to remove the first snack from the list.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-worker-j5mh2)

If you click the button for example, four times in a short amount of time. They render nicely, but when the first one is to be deleted, they all disappear and reappear abnormally.

I understand that it's partially the state re-renderings fault, however, I'm not sure how to handle it in a way that the removal is handled gracefully without affecting the rendering of other snacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after many hours of trial and error, I found a solution that works so far. Moving and reading the snacks outside of the state helped with the bizarre rendering problems, and with it, I was able to create a message que which works well.

Working example
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-worker-j5mh2)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) document, you will notice that it's returning an array of deleted elements and not the initial array.

You can correct it by splicing **then** updating:

```
snacks.splice(-1, 1);
addSnacks(snacks);
```

However you are still going to have some weird behavior and you might need to use a [keyed list](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i saw your solution, but i was really trying to find out why it happens - here is why:

when u call a useState hook from an async function's callback, you should use the callback format of the hook to make sure that you are working with the latest value. example:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

const addMessage = ( message ) => {
  setMessages( prevMessages => {//prevMessages will be the latest value of messages
    return [ ...prevMessages, message ];
  });
};

const removeMessage = ( index ) => {
  setMessages( prevMessages => {//prevMessages will be the latest value of messages
    let newMessages = [...prevMessages];
    newMessages.splice( index, 1 );
    return newMessages;
  });
};
```